# Getting a "Missing token: ASSIGN" error when running OpenModelica script through a batch file

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am trying to run an OpenModelica script using a DOS .bat file. But facing some issues.
The batch file runmodelica.bat has

```
%OPENMODELICAHOME%\bin\omc testscript.mos
```

The file testscript.mos is

```
loadModel(Modelica)
getErrorString()
loadFile("HelloWorld.mo")
simulate(HelloWorld)
getErrorString()
```

If I run the commands in the testscript.mos file from an OM Shell by changing to that directory, everything works fine. But If I run the batch file from the DOS prompt, I get the following error

```
Error processing file: testscript.mos
[C:/Users/blahblah/testscript.mos:2:1-2:1:writable] Error: Missing token: ASSIGN

# Error encountered! Exiting...
# Please check the error message and the flags.

Execution failed!
```

The HelloWorld.mo file comes with the standard installation and I haven't modified it

```
class HelloWorld
  Real x(start = 1);
  parameter Real a = 1;
equation
  der(x) = - a * x;
end HelloWorld;
```

I am new to OpenModelica and searched online but couldn't find a solution. Any help is appreciated.

All the commands run in the OM Shell but not when invoked from the bat file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script code needs to be valid Modelica, so you need ; after each command.

```
loadModel(Modelica);
getErrorString();
loadFile("HelloWorld.mo");
simulate(HelloWorld);
getErrorString();
```